# Why am I viewing some pages like this?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm seeing some pages like this, mostly forums, and I don't know why. The source code is readable and also if I copy and paste somewhere else. This is the [link](http://tabmixplus.org/support/viewpage.php?t=3&p=links) for this:

[image: img]

It occurs in Firefox 95 and Chrome 99 under Windows 7, but Firefox 54 and Internet Explorer 8 shows it perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 97.0.2

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a problem with system font (Lucida); according Mozilla Support question “[Text on random websites replaced with `đ`" characters](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1255114)” reinstalling it should help.

Comment: Sure it did help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I understood what happened.

I have installed **Lucida Grande** and **Lucida Grande Bold**. When previewing each one looks fine:

- [Lucida Grande](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vltu.jpg)
- [Lucida Grande Bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC9RQ.jpg)

But looking closely at its names they have the same. So deleting Lucida Grande Bold solves the problem.

Thanks to [@myf’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1708675/167207) for the clue.